# Is it possible to install Redis 5.0.3 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, redis

How can I install Redis 5.0.3? I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: The current version of Redis for Ubuntu 22.04 is 6.0.16. If you need 5.0.3 specifically, then a Docker container will be your best bet. This will avoid the problem of Redis being upgraded when you perform a system update later.

Comment: Can i install without Docker directly on VM

Comment: There are options to do this, but it's going to be a complete nightmare for anyone who does not love "geeking out" about the nitty-gritty of manually managing dependency hierarchies. If Docker is not an option, then you may want to compile from source, as that would get around the problem of 3rd-party repositories changing their versions.

Comment: Can i get repository link please??

Comment: I do not have any links to share, otherwise I would have done so. You will need to do the legwork to find one that claims to be compatible with 22.04. I have been using Docker containers for situations like this for almost 2 years and it has resolved 99% of the edge case scenarios that I need to support people with. Repos are unreliable long-term.